# symfony mpdf generated pdf download via ajax

Tags: ajax, symfony, mpdf

I post a data(browser input) via ajax to the controller and process the data and made the mpdf out as

```
$a=base64_encode($pdf->Output('abc.pdf', 'S'));
```

and retuned the data as json response.following is my ajax.

```
$.ajax({        
    type: "POST",
    url: path,
    dataType: "json",
    ontentType: "application/Json;charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(param),
    success: function (resp) {
        var a = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(resp)));
        $('.result').html('<object type="application/pdf" data="data:application/pdf;base64,' + a + '" width="100%" height="800">No Support</object>');
   }
}
```

I have been stuck on this since long.

Comment: What is your question? What is an expected outcome of this?

Comment: @Finwe i just want the input data to be processed and the pdf to be generated and displayed against a single button click via ajax. BUt i am unable to get the pdf within the object tag.